# Time Machine is trying to backup

Tags: macos, time-machine

I noticed my Time Machine is trying to backup 137G of data into my Time Capsule... I thought Time Machine suppose to do increments.. How is this increment when I only have 137G worth of data on my hard drive? before TM was always trying to backup gigs of data even when there was not that much change on my computer...

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you re-installed OS X lately or are you trying to run it from a different user than usual?

Comment: Apple did data transfer from my old computer into a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research and found this: [Time Machine Full Backup Issue.](http://pondini.org/TM/D3.html)

Here is what it says on the site:

> Time Machine will always do a full backup in these circumstances:
>
> - Backing-up from a new disk or partition (only that disk/partition gets a full backup).
> - Backing-up to a new or erased disk or partition.
> - After a full restore (not a "smart update") from a "clone" such as CarbonCopyCloner or SuperDuper.  This includes getting a new HD or
>     erasing your current one, and using the clone to restore your data. 
>     Effective with Lion 10.7.x, you may be able to prevent it via item #B6).
> - After replacing or erasing your internal HD, and putting your data back “piecemeal.”  This includes dragging selected items or restoring
>     selected items via the Time Machine “Star Wars” display.  Effective
>     with Lion 10.7.x, you may be able to prevent it via item #B6).
> - Going many days (at least 10, usually many more) without a backup, if a lot of changes have been made.